# Retrofit posting through @Field makes value as an array

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

Using Django web API for connecting mobile client, I use Retrofit @Field to post the values to API, it works perfectly when I tested using postman, but did the same  in mobile client using Retrofit POST posting parameters in 
@Field

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Urls.API_REGISTER)
    fun register(
        @Header("Content-Type") contentType: String,
        @Field("username") userName: String,
        @Field("password") password: String,
        @Field("email") email: String
    ): Observable<JsonElement>
```

and getting the parameters' value as an array element like below

```
{'username': ['kabildev'], 'password': ['Kabil@123'], 'email': ['kapil@outlook.com']}
```

Even I had tried setting Content-Type to application/json but no luck, Is there any reason why does it form an array value, FYI, when posting from postman it takes as below

```
{'username': 'kabildev', 'password': 'Kabil@123', 'email': 'kapil@outlook.com'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced similar issue that got rectified when **@Field** was replaced by **@Body** creating a new data class named **User** and making the request as below

```
@POST(Urls.API_REGISTER)
fun register(
    @Body user: User
): Observable<JsonElement>
```

Also don't forget to remove the @FormUrlEncoded, and let the **User** model be as below

```
data class User(@SerializedName("username") val userName: String,
            @SerializedName("password") val password: String,
            @SerializedName("email") val email: String)
```